# Using regular expressions to extract a value in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have several strings in the rough form:

```
[some text] [some number] [some more text]
```

I want to extract the text in [some number] using the Java regex classes.

I know roughly what regular expression I want to use (though all suggestions are welcome). What I'm really interested in are the Java calls to take the regex string and use it on the source data to produce the value of [some number].

I should add that I'm only interested in a single [some number] (basically, the first instance). The source strings are short and I'm not going to be looking for multiple occurrences of [some number].

Answer (score 380, accepted):

Full example:

```
private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)(.*)");
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create matcher for pattern p and given string
    Matcher m = p.matcher("Testing123Testing");

    // if an occurrence if a pattern was found in a given string...
    if (m.find()) {
        // ...then you can use group() methods.
        System.out.println(m.group(0)); // whole matched expression
        System.out.println(m.group(1)); // first expression from round brackets (Testing)
        System.out.println(m.group(2)); // second one (123)
        System.out.println(m.group(3)); // third one (Testing)
    }
}
```

Since you're looking for the first number, you can use such regexp:

```
^\D+(\d+).*
```

and `m.group(1)` will return you the first number. Note that signed numbers can contain a minus sign:

```
^\D+(-?\d+).*
```

Comment: Don't forget to reuse Patter object. Compiling of patter take huge amount of time.

Comment: Agreed.  Usually I'd define the pattern as a private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("..."); But that's just me.

Comment: we can simply use Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

Comment: You may also reuse the Matcher. Call the Matcher's reset() method between each use. If you are sharing the matcher across multiple concurrent threads you should synchronize the operation.

Comment: @AllainLalonde Are there any explanation or a link to an explanation?

Comment: There is one caveat to this approach, hinted at in @Marquez 's answer: the Matcher is a state machine. This also includes that `p.matcher(<string>).group()` will throw an error, because the matcher was only created. You need to actually store the matcher and run it by calling `.find()`, before you call .find() on it. As a FP guy, this didn't occur to me for the previous two hours (logging .find() would always return true, but .group() would always throw...).

Comment: I meant to say "run .find() before you can run .group() on it", but was too slow to edit...

Answer (score 53):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex1 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("hello1234goodboy789very2345");
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1234
789
2345
```

Comment: The question specifically asks for only the FIRST occurrence of numbers.

Answer (score 37):

Allain basically has the java code, so you can use that. However, his expression only matches *if* your numbers are only preceded by a stream of word characters.

```
"(\\d+)"
```

should be able to find the first string of digits. You don't need to specify what's before it, if you're sure that it's going to be the first string of digits. Likewise, there is no use to specify what's after it, unless you want that. If you just want the number, and are sure that it will be the first string of one or more digits then that's all you need.

If you expect it to be offset by spaces, it will make it even more distinct to specify

```
"\\s+(\\d+)\\s+"
```

might be better.

If you need all three parts, this will do:

```
"(\\D+)(\\d+)(.*)"
```

**EDIT** The Expressions given by Allain and Jack suggest that you need to specify some subset of non-digits in order to capture *digits*. If you tell the regex engine you're looking for `\d` then it's going to ignore everything before the digits. If J or A's expression *fits* your pattern, then the whole match *equals* the *input string*. And there's no reason to specify it. It probably slows a clean match down, if it isn't totally ignored.

Comment: you can test Axemans' hypothesis by running a sample test and checking the performance of his vs. A/J solution.

Comment: Don't you need to specify the beginning and end of the string.  Otherwise things like 124xxx123xxx would be matched even though it doesn't fit into his syntax? Or are ^ and $ implicit?

Comment: Allain, yours would fail as well. You and Jack make an assumption that non-digit characters will precede the digits. They either do or they don't. In which case, none of these expressions will parse this line. I repeat that *as specified*, the pattern for the digits is enough.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), the Java [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) class also has several methods that can work with regular expressions, in your case the code will be:

```
"ab123abc".replaceFirst("\\D*(\\d*).*", "$1")
```

where `\\D` is a non-digit character.

Answer (score 11):

In Java 1.4 and up:

```
String input = "...";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]+([0-9]+)[^0-9]+").matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String someNumberStr = matcher.group(1);
    // if you need this to be an int:
    int someNumberInt = Integer.parseInt(someNumberStr);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This function collect all matching sequences from string. In this example it takes all email addresses from string.

```
static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
        + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})";

public List<String> getAllEmails(String message) {      
    List<String> result = null;
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN).matcher(message);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        result = new ArrayList<String>();
        result.add(matcher.group());

        while (matcher.find()) {
            result.add(matcher.group());
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

For `message = "adf@gmail.com, <another@osiem.osiem>>>> lalala@aaa.pl"` it will create List of 3 elements.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.+(\\d+).+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Testing123Testing");

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: -1. Because `.+` greedily consumes characters, `\d+` only captures the `"3"` from `"123"`. Also, inside string literals, you need to escape the backslash (your example will not compile).

Answer (score 3):

### Simple Solution

```
// Regexplanation:
// ^       beginning of line
// \\D+    1+ non-digit characters
// (\\d+)  1+ digit characters in a capture group
// .*      0+ any character
String regexStr = "^\\D+(\\d+).*";

// Compile the regex String into a Pattern
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexStr);

// Create a matcher with the input String
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputStr);

// If we find a match
if (m.find()) {
    // Get the String from the first capture group
    String someDigits = m.group(1);
    // ...do something with someDigits
}
```

### Solution in a Util Class

```
public class MyUtil {
    private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\D+(\\d+).*");
    private static Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("");

    // Assumptions: inputStr is a non-null String
    public static String extractFirstNumber(String inputStr){
        // Reset the matcher with a new input String
        matcher.reset(inputStr);

        // Check if there's a match
        if(matcher.find()){
            // Return the number (in the first capture group)
            return matcher.group(1);
        }else{
            // Return some default value, if there is no match
            return null;
        }
    }
}

...

// Use the util function and print out the result
String firstNum = MyUtil.extractFirstNumber("Testing4234Things");
System.out.println(firstNum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look you can do it using StringTokenizer

```
String str = "as:"+123+"as:"+234+"as:"+345;
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"as:");

while(st.hasMoreTokens())
{
  String k = st.nextToken();    // you will get first numeric data i.e 123
  int kk = Integer.parseInt(k);
  System.out.println("k string token in integer        " + kk);

  String k1 = st.nextToken();   //  you will get second numeric data i.e 234
  int kk1 = Integer.parseInt(k1);
  System.out.println("new string k1 token in integer   :" + kk1);

  String k2 = st.nextToken();   //  you will get third numeric data i.e 345
  int kk2 = Integer.parseInt(k2);
  System.out.println("k2 string token is in integer   : " + kk2);
}
```

Since we are taking these numeric data into three different variables we can use this data anywhere in the code (for further use)

Answer (score 0):

How about `[^\\d]*([0-9]+[\\s]*[.,]{0,1}[\\s]*[0-9]*).*` I think it would take care of numbers with fractional part. 
I included white spaces and included `,` as possible separator.
I'm trying to get the numbers out of a string including floats and taking into account that the user might make a mistake and include white spaces while typing the number.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can use simple .split("REGEXP") method available in java.lang.String. For example:

```
String input = "first,second,third";

//To retrieve 'first' 
input.split(",")[0] 
//second
input.split(",")[1]
//third
input.split(",")[2]
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are reading from file then this can help you

```
              try{
             InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) mnpMainBean.getUploadedBulk().getInputStream();
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
             String line;
             //Ref:03
             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.matches("[A-Z],\\d,(\\d*,){2}(\\s*\\d*\\|\\d*:)+")) {
                     String[] splitRecord = line.split(",");
                     //do something
                 }
                 else{
                     br.close();
                     //error
                     return;
                 }
             }
                br.close();

             }
         }
         catch (IOException  ioExpception){
             logger.logDebug("Exception " + ioExpception.getStackTrace());
         }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\D+)(\\d+)(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("this is your number:1234 thank you");
if (m.find()) {
    String someNumberStr = m.group(2);
    int someNumberInt = Integer.parseInt(someNumberStr);
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: Downvote for just repeating correct answers that have been given a long time ago without adding any additional value