# Regular Expression Help - String - JWE-766.1.pdf - Pattern - Extract 766

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like some help with a regular expression.

I have some files like this:

- JWE-766.1.pdf
- JWE-766.2.pdf
- JWE-768.1.pdf
- JWE-770.1.pdf

I would like a regex pattern to extract the number after 'JWE-'. i.e. 766.

Also, a regex expression to extract 1 and 2 from JWE-766.1.pdf and JWE-766.2.pdf respectively.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Just extract whatever number comes before ".pdf"?

Comment: What's the input like? Just a file name at a time, or is it some sort of list?

Comment: Hi NullUserException,

File name at a time.

(nice username)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^JWE-([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.pdf$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("your string here");

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); //first number group
    System.out.println(m.group(2)); //second number group
}
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java)

Also, make sure to reuse the `Pattern p` object if you're looping through a series of strings

Comment: Hey.

Thanks very much. Alas, that pattern has an error of "Invalid Escape Sequence". Hmmmn.....I shall find out why :-)

Comment: It may be possible that Java is complaining over the `\\d` part. I changed it to use `[0-9]` instead.

Comment: `\\d` is correct.  He was probably using your regex in its original form, before you doubled all the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is more variety to the pattern than this, I would just use substring manipulation in this case.

ie

```
string s = "JWE-766.1.pdf";
string firstNumber = s.substring( s.indexOf("-" +1), s.indexOf(".") );
string secondNumber = "JWE-766.1.pdf".substring( s.indexOf("." +1), s.lastIndexOf(".") );
```

Comment: Hello there.

I would have done this approach, however, this is a problem because I also have files like: JWE-11.1.pdf

Comment: @Jamie updated my answer to reflect your detail.  To me, it still feels like substring is the better choice in this case, but to each his own :)

Answer (score 1):

JWE-(\d+).(\d+).pdf

should do the trick.

of course when you are creating the string:

```
Pattern  p = Pattern.compile("JWE-(\\d+)\.(\\d+)\\.pdf");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s); // s contains your filename
if (m.matches()) { 
   String fullName = m.group(0);
   int firstIndex = m.group(1); // 766
   int secondIndex = m.group(2); // 1
}
```

Have fun

Comment: Thanks :-) I marked sigint's answer as the right one so he could get some reputation. I have upvoted yours though. Thanks again! :D

Comment: :-) i voted for his answer too coz it appeared while i was finishing mine

Answer (score 1):

You can use parentheses for capturing groups, and then use Matcher.group(int) to retrieve them after matching.

Try the pattern "^JWE-(\d+)\.(\d?)\.pdf$" and I think group one should be the 766, and group 2 should be 1.

However, as stated above, if the file names are consistent in length, straight manipulation by index will be faster.

...one minute too slow. The Elf King is quick like the wind.