# How to parse out Timestamp from this String?

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I have this sample string:

```
Sample string 1:
A^1.1#B^1#I^2#f^0#p^1#d^2010-07-21T08:52:05.222ZKHBDGSLKHFBDSLKFGNIF#%$%^$#^$XLGCREWIGMEWCERG

Sample string 2:
A^1.1#B^1#f^0#p^1#d^2010-07-22T07:02:05.370ZREGHCOIMIYR$#^$#^$#^EWMGCOINNNNNNVVVRFGGYVJ667VTG
```

So, from these strings, I need to take out the time stamp:

```
2010-07-21T08:52:05.222 or
2010-07-22T07:02:05.370
```

Basically values b/w `d^ and Z`

What is the best ("smartest") way to do this? substring(), regex?

Comment: The examples look like ISO8601 format which is very common, that may help you find a 'built in' parser.

Comment: Could you please refrain from using MY avatar?! >_<

Comment: @pavel lol, np, I didn't see a "copyright" on your avatar, so took it. :)

Comment: thanks :-)  Your duck is cool btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3})");
//you could also use "d\\^(.*)Z" as your regex patern
Matcher m = p.matcher("your string here");

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); //print out the timestamp
}
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java)

Also, make sure to reuse the `Pattern p` object if you're looping through a series of strings

Comment: Since it's always between the "d^" and "Z" wouldn't it be easier just to do d\^(.*?)Z and use the capture group?

Comment: @fy-tide Ah, you are correct. Edited to show both strict and simple regex patterns.

Answer (score 2):

With two small assumptions you can do it without a regex.

1. The `^d` right before the date string is the first one that appears in the text.  I assume that delimiter always means "A date follows."
2. That date format looks pretty regular, so I'm assuming the length won't change.

Just get the index of the starting `^d` delimiter to find out where the date starts and use the length to get then ending index.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "A^1.1#B^1#I^2#f^0#p^1#d^2010-07-21T08:52:05.222ZKHBDGSLKHFBDSLKFGNIF#%$%^$#^$XLGCREWIGMEWCERG";
    String s2 = "A^1.1#B^1#f^0#p^1#d^2010-07-22T07:02:05.370ZREGHCOIMIYR$#^$#^$#^EWMGCOINNNNNNVVVRFGGYVJ667VTG";

    System.out.println( parseDate(s1) );
    System.out.println( parseDate(s2) );
}

public static String parseDate(String s) {
    int start = s.indexOf("d^") + 2;
    int length = 23;

    String date = s.substring(start, start + length);
    return date;
}
```

Output:

> 2010-07-21T08:52:05.222
>   2010-07-22T07:02:05.370

Comment: ok, so from good programming practice, isn't assuming the length of a string bad?

Comment: @zengr: I have to assume it because I only have 2 samples to look at.  You shouldn't assume it and you shouldn't have to.  You should be able to find out if that date format is fixed length.  The regular expression you accepted is assuming a known format too.

Comment: @zengr: I will add though, if you can't verify that those two assumptions will be true for any input, you should definitely stick with the regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a regex, something like `(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d{3})`.

You might want to get fancier, and prevent months outside the range 01-12, days outside of 01-31 etc. for hours but it should be good enough as is given the sample data that you've provided.

Substrings might work if the date is always prefixed with ^d, but I still think the regex is cleaner.