# substring all occurrence of current Timestamp in a dynamic string in java

Tags: java

I have a string that is dynamic i.e

> [some text] [current timestamp] [some more text] [some text] [current
>   timestamp] [some more text]

How do i substring/replace all occurrences of current timestamp as the string length keeps changing.

Comment: you should build a regular expression that captures the timestamp you try to replace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302870/how-to-parse-out-timestamp-from-this-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll) method of `String` class.

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

The `given regular expression` in your case will be the current time stamp. and `replacement` could be empty string. `""` OR whatever you want to replace with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)` or `String.replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`.

For example:

```
String text = "Pmaingi12345123312OtherTextAndSomeother124123"
text.replaceFirst("regex", "change to this text");
```