# Java data structure read numeric content from a string

Tags: java, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Regular Expressions to Extract a Value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java)

For example, the input string is `AB100FF10`.  I need to read `100` and `10` from the string. Is there any classes/objects in Java that I can use?

Comment: Oh, I come to realize that I can use regular expression

Comment: I am asking the data structure that reads numeric data from combination of numeric and string

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java

Comment: @SecureFish Data structures don't do these things, what you mean is objects/classes.

Comment: I come up with the solution without running it: ^.(0-9)+.$. Following is my explaination: any char among 0 to 9, at least one of them appear once or more than one time. before it or after it, any character matches

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String[] nums = "AB100FF10".split("\\D+");
for (String num : nums) {
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

---

Other than that, you could try passing the string to a class like [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner("AB100FF10").useDelimiter("\\D+");
while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println(scan.nextInt());
}
```

**Edit**: using `\\D` instead of `\\w` as a delimiter, as Bohemian suggested in his answer and comments.

Comment: You beat me to it. I tried to delete my post. Not sure if it actually went though.

Comment: Have you tested your code? (Because it doesn't work)

Comment: :P `Scanner` is slow though. The post is deleted, but you should be able to see it, and restore it if you like.

Comment: @Bohemian no, I haven't, but this shouldn't be about spoonfeeding. The idea is there.

Comment: It's an idea, just not a *good* idea. Compare it with my answer (your regex isn't the best - for example your regex would try to parse a bracket `(` as an integer.

Comment: yep, `\\D` is better indeed, I put a comment there, just because of that: "_supposing the string is only letters and number_". I will update my answer with `\\D`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `split(<non-digits>)`, like this:

```
String[] numbers = "AB100FF10CCC".replaceAll("(^\\D*|\\D*$)", "").split("\\D+"); // "[100, 10]"
```

Now `numbers` contains an array of Strings that are all guaranteed to be numeric. You can use `Integer.parseInt()` to get `ints`.

The `replaceAll("(^\\D*|\\D*$)", "")` is used to trim non-digits from the front and back of the input string, otherwise split() will give you a blank string as the first/last element. It just makes to code simpler, rather than having to test the first/last specially.

As a method, it would look like this:

```
public static int[] parseInts(String input) {        
    String[] numbers = input.replaceAll("(^\\D*|\\D*$)", "").split("\\D+");
    int[] result = new int[numbers.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        result[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: maybe from the front and back of input string it will be replaceAll("(^\\D*|\\w+\\D*$)", "")?

Comment: @Bohemian. Before running the code, I want to understand the mechanism correctly. what I will get after calling replaceAll(). Do I get "100FF10" or "100 10"? If I just get "100FF10", what will happen if I have "A100B1000C2000D3000"?  In this case I need split all the integers embedded in a string?

Comment: It's all in my explanation: "[replaceAll] is used to trim non-digits from the front and back of the input string (etc)". ie "AB100FF10CCC" --> "00FF10". The code will work for any number of ints embedded.

Comment: @maks: no `\D` is the right choice: it means "non-digits"

Comment: @Bohemian: "AB100FF10CCC".replaceAll("(^\\D*|\\D*$)", "") will make 10010 string because interrnal FF also match the pattern

Comment: @maks no it won't: the regex only matches on the **END** of the string - see the little `^` and `$`?

Comment: @Bohemian: Does the ^\D* match at the beginning of the string and the \D*$ at the end?

Comment: @maks yes `^` means start of input, `$` means end of input, \D* means 0-n non-digits. Put them together using regex `OR` (ie `(A|B)` means `A OR B`) and you trim all non-digits from the start and end of the input

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only integers you can do the following:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
char[] characters = "AB100FF10".toCharArray();
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
     if (Character.isDigit(characters[i])) 
        buf.append(characters[i]);
     else if (buf.length() != 0) {
         numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(buf.toString()));
         buf = new StringBuffer();
     }
}
```

After that you will have an arrayList of numbers

Comment: This is what I did in the interview. And the interviewer asked for more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Did interviewer ask you about this in the context of regular expressions?

Comment: Not exactly, I think he is expecting more concise code

Answer (score 0):

I think pattern might be a better solution to because pattern object is more powerful comparing to simple String split() method.

for example, following code can resolve the same problem without any exception

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test[0]);
while(m.find()){
  int x = Integer.parseInt( m.group() );
}
```

But if I use `String.split()`, there is one NumberFormatException is hard to dealt with.For example, below code can't escape NumberFormatException

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < test.length; i++){
  String[] numstr= test[i].split("\\D+");
  try{              
    for(int j=0; j<numstr.length;j++){
      if( numstr[j] == null || numstr[j] == ""){
    System.out.println("empty string \n");
      }
      else
       Integer.parseInt(numstr[j]);                 
  }catch(NumberFormatException ie){
      ie.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```