# Regular expression in java to parse a string

Tags: java

I have a String. The string is  "New England 12 Philidelphia 24 (Final)". I need a regaular expression from which i should able to retrieve items like.

1. First Team -- New England
2. First Team Score -- 12
3. Second Team -- Philidelpia
4. Second Team Score -- 24
5. Result -- Final or whatever in the braces.

Comment: Will you need to parse "Hannover 96 2 Schalke 04 1 (Final)"?

Comment: "Hannover 96 Schalke 04 (Final)" Something like this. But not the extra 2 and 1 after the scores.

Comment: My point exactly. The extra 2 and 1 *is* the score.

Comment: @Thilo not even mentioning München 1860 :D

Comment: Or 1. FC Saarbruecken, to put the digits in front.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) showing how to use regex and groups to extract the data you want.

FYI, although it will work for just the input you provided, this code will scan through input containing *multiple* results like this, matching all of them in the `while` loop.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    String input = "New England 12 Philidelphia 24 (Final)";
    String regex = "([a-zA-Z ]+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+([a-zA-Z ]+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+\\((\\w+)\\)";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( regex ).matcher( input);
    while (matcher.find( )) {
        String team1 = matcher.group(1);
        String score1 = matcher.group(2);
        String team2 = matcher.group(3);
        String score2 = matcher.group(4);
        String result = matcher.group(5);
        System.out.println( team1 + " scored " + score1 + ", " + team2 + " scored " + score2 + ", which was " + result);
    }
}
```

Output

```
New England scored 12, Philidelphia scored 24, which was Final
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
"(\\w+) (\\d+) (\\w+) (\\d+) \((\\w+)\)"
```

Comment: How can it be "tested"? It doesn't even compile! (hint: this is a *java* question)

Comment: Oh my goodness. Dint see that. Sorry, that was in c#, but this regex should work fine.

Comment: I don't have an idea how to extract from the groups in java, so could just give you the regex. Have a look at the solution in [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java/8116229#8116229) to get an idea in using the above expression for extracting values from groups

Comment: i guess u have to add extra \ like "(\\w+) (\\d+) (\\w+) (\\d+) \\((\\w+)\\)" so that u escape \ in java.

Comment: yes to escape a `\ or (` we use a \, but do you need to do it in case of `\w` or `\d` as well, as you did? I dont think so! Did that work?

Comment: It din't work. You have to use extra \ to escape backlslah in java.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
^[\D]*\s*\d*\s*[\D]*\s*\d*\s*\([\D]*\)$
```