# Breaking down components in a String sentence by user

Tags: java

For example: 
Someone orders some movie passes: 
**User enters :** 3 tickets for Taken 2 at 17.50
How can I extract the quantity of tickets purchased, know the movie selected and total the costs from the entered string.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
                 String Mac1
         System.out.println("Enter num of tickets, movie & (at) ticket price:");
         Mac1 = input.nextLine();

         String Mov1[]= Mac1.split(", ");

           for (int i = 0; i < Mov1.length; i++) 
           {
               System.out.print(Mov1[i]);

           }
```

Comment: Are inputs always of the form "N tickets for This_Movie at This_Time"?

Comment: Look at <http://stackoverflow.com/q/237061/1056693>

Answer (score 2):

Using regex appears a better fit here:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d+) tickets for (.*) at (.*)").matcher(Mac1);
if (m.matches()) {
  int tickets = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
  String movie = m.group(2);
  double cost = Double.parseDouble(m.group(3));
  double total = tickets * cost;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like regular expressions are the best tool for the job (no matter how bad it looks):

```
(\\d+) tickets for (.*) at (\\d{1,2})[.:](\\d{2})
```

Comment: @ Chris, Number of tickets, for This_Movie at This price, I might need to add time into the string.