# How do I parse the following format string?

Tags: java, rdf, n-triples

I have data in following format

```
<foo bar> <property abc> <this foo bar> .
```

Now there are essentially 4 parts in this string: `foo bar`; `property abc`; `this foo bar`; and `.`. How do I tokenize the above string into these four parts?

Comment: What are you trying to parse? (just in case there's some library that does it for you)

Comment: googling "rdf parser java" got me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73445/what-are-some-good-java-rdf-libraries

Comment: If it's RDF why wouldn't you use an RDF library?????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Regular Expressions to Extract a Value in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java)

Comment: Note that as far as RDF serializations go, the snipped you've shown could be N-Triples, Turtle, or N3.  [N-Triples](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-testcases/#ntriples) is a line based format, and parsing each line as you've requested will be fine, except that the object in each triple may also be an literal, which would not look like `<...>`. Turtle and N3 allow much more complicated expressions in addition to these simple expressions, and the line-based approach will not work on those serializations.  It would be much better to use a dedicated RDF parser than to roll your own and run into problems.

Comment: @texasbruce As phrased, the possible duplicate does seem like a good fit, but because Fraz is looking to parse RDF documents, it's likely that the format is more complicated than the question suggests.  I don't think that the answers to that question will necessarily be adequate for Fraz's _actual_ task (though it's a perfect fit for the  question as asked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] array = string.split("> ");

for (int i = 0; i < array.length -1; i++){
    System.out.println(array[i] + ">");
}
System.out.println(array[array.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested if you want to parse RDF graphs just use a library like [Apache Jena](http://jena.apache.org) (*disclaimer* - I am one of the developers).

If your problem is more that you need direct control over the parsing process then there are several options:

- Jena has a [TokenizerText](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/riot/tokens/TokenizerText.html) class which can tokenize NTriple/Turtle/SPARQL like data if you want to work with the data at the textual level
- You can implement [StreamRDF](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/riot/system/StreamRDF.html) interface and use this with the built-in parsers to control what happens to the data as it is parsed at the triple/quad level