# Extracting the terms of a String using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

Sorry for the bad title, but really could not find some other words for it. But, I am working in java and i have the following pattern matching to do.

The pattern is `(\\w)*(\\s+)(\\w)*(\\,)(\\s*)(\\w)*(\\,)?(\\s*)(\\w)*`

The String to be matched is of the type `"add    r0,    r1,    r2"`. 
Now, how can I extract the all the individual strings from the above string, ie. `add,r0,r1 and r2`?
To make it clearer, if the input string were `"mov   r1,   r4"`, I would like to extract `mov, r1 and r4.` 
How to go about this?

Comment: Look at the `Matcher` API and its group-related methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Regular Expressions to Extract a Value in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java)

Comment: `input.split("[\\s,]+");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
String yourinput="add r0, r1, r2"
String[] s=yourinput.split("[\\s,]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Don't try to match the full string using a complex regex and use `String#split(regex)` to split it using space or comma i.e. `"[, ]"` and get your tokens from resulting array.

```
String input = "add r0, r1, r2";
String[] arr = input.split("[ ,]+"));
// [add, r0, r1, r2]
```

Comment: I would like to avoid splitting. Is there anyway I can directly access the terms, like in Ocaml?

Comment: What would be good reason to avoid split call and make it more complicated to solve?

Comment: I was wondering if there was any other direct access method. If it is not, then I guess split is the only option?

Comment: split is definitely the simplest.