# How to split a complex string?

Tags: java, regex

```
String ="(Buy) 655500 - (Sell) 656500";
```

I want to split this string by ignoring `(Buy)`, `-`, `(Sell)`.

The final result I want is like this `655500 656500`.

Above is the example..Actually my string contain UTF-8 characters..But I left it here

Comment: Can you please let us know what have you tried so far to solve this?

Comment: If your syntax is always like that you can just split on whitespaces and always know the array indexes of the numbers...

Comment: if the answer worked please do give accept the answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular Expression

```
    String src = "(Buy) 655500 - (Sell) 656500";
    String reg = "[0-9]+";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(reg);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(src);
    while(matcher.find()) {
       System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

Comment: I think this is the best compatible with my code..By using regular expression, this is the best for UTF8 character condition..Thanks Longwayto

Answer (score 1):

```
String string = "(Buy) 655500 - (Sell) 656500";

String needed = string.replaceAll("[\"(Buy)(Sell)-]", "");
```

this should work maybe ... needed is the String that should give you the needed result.

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach would be to define a regular expression pattern match for the sequence and extract the values from that.

[Using Regular Expressions to Extract a Value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If your syntax is always like that you can just split like that :

```
String string = "(Buy) 655500 - (Sell) 656500";
String replaced= string.replaceAll("[(Buy)(Sell)]", "");
String[] values = replaced.split("-");
```

here :
     value[0] will be 655500 
and values[1] will be 656500

If Your requirement is different then comment.

Answer (score 0):

another way:

```
String baseStr = "(Buy) 655500 - (Sell) 656500";  
String buy = baseStr.split("-")[0].replaceAll("\\D+", "");  
String sell = baseStr.split("-")[1].replaceAll("\\D+", "");  

System.out.println("Base String: " + baseStr);  
System.out.println("Buy String : " + buy);  
System.out.println("Sell String: " + sell);
```

and here's the output:

```
Base String: (Buy) 655500 - (Sell) 656500  
Buy String : 655500  
Sell String: 656500
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    String text = "(Buy) 655500 - (Sell) 656500";
    List<String> parts = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(text.split("\\D")));
    parts.removeAll(Arrays.asList(""));
    System.out.println(parts);
```

Fnd you will get list of numbers in your string.