# How to extract date section from filename?

Tags: java, regex

I need to find a regex to extract date section from the name of several files.

In particular I have these two formats:

- `ATC0200720140828080610.xls`
- `ATC0200720140901080346_UFF_ACC.xls`

I use these two regex to check file name format:

- `^ATC02007[0-9]{14}.xls$`
- `^ATC02007[0-9]{14}_UFF_ACC.xls$`

But I need a regex to extract a specific section:

```
constant | yyyyMMddHHmmss |   constant
    ^            ^               ^
ATC02007 | 20140901080346 | _UFF_ACC.xls
```

Both regex I'm using match the entire file name, so I can't use to extract the middle section, so which is the right expression?

Comment: how about `fileName.substring(8,8 + 14)`? (not sure about the values)

Comment: Use capturing groups.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Regular Expressions to Extract a Value in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Just use round brackets to contain the numbers you want.

`^ATC02007([0-9]{14})(_UFF_ACC)?.xls$`

See [example](http://regex101.com/r/xD2nG4/1). The numbers are captured in group 1`$1`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use capturing groups.

```
^(ATC02007)([0-9]{14})((?:[^.]*)?\\.xls)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kD7eC3/1)

GRoup index 1 contains the first constant and group 2 contains date and time and group 3 contains the third constant.

```
String s = "ATC0200720140828080610.xls\n" + 
        "ATC0200720140901080346_UFF_ACC.xls";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?m)^(ATC02007)([0-9]{14})((?:[^.]*)?\\.xls)$");
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
}
```

**Output:**

```
ATC02007
20140828080610
.xls
ATC02007
20140901080346
_UFF_ACC.xls
```

Comment: or `^(.*)([0-9]{14})((?:[^.]*)?\.xls)$`