# Selenium WebDriver with Eclipse: How can i set a condition on a Span-Element?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm programming selenium test-cases using eclipse.
I want to test an online-shop and want to see if the functionality is right.

I want to test, if the number "785" is over 100 . There are lot of span-tags and a lot of sites, so I want to test it automatically.

Here is the code-snippet, I want to test.

```
<span class="left inline-block">Angezeigte Artikel: 1 bis 24 (von 785)</span>
```

I can find the span-tag with this code-snippet but I can't get the text and set a specific condition.

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("span")).findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(.,'von')]" )).getText();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the text from the `span` element, use [regular expressions with saving groups to extract the desired value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java) and [cast it to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java):

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(., 'von')]" )).getText();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\d+ bis \d+ \(von (\d+)\)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

if (m.find()) {
    int value = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
}
```