# Regex to extract Domain name based on Path

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to extract server names from below json based on the path.
So ideally I should get `server1` & `server2` the string between `https` & `/upload/image/app` as output and ignore the youtube url.

```
{
    "url1" : "https://server1/upload/image/app/test1.jpg",
    "video" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7QaD3l1yQA",
    "type" : "youtube",
    "url2" : "https://server2/upload/image/app/test2.jpg"
}
```

Tried this, but i know this wont work:

```
https://(.*?)/upload/image/app
```

Comment: What is the question here? You said it yourself: use a regex to extract the informaiton from the string you get when iterating over the entries...

Comment: Not able to formulate a regex that does this, the youtube url is making it difficult

Comment: In what programming language/environment are you planning to do this?

Comment: Then post your attempts so far and point out what is not working. How else should we help with that otherwise?

Comment: Updated my original question.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:http|https)\:\/\/(.*?)\/(?:.*?)$
```

This should do the trick. Examples:

```
<?php
preg_match("/^(?:http|https)\:\/\/(.*?)\/(?:.*?)$/", "https://server1/upload/image/app/test1.jpg", $matches);
echo $matches[1]; //server1
?>
```

It's not so difficult to work with regex, I suggest you to start learining at least basics because they may be useful

Comment: My input is not a single URL but the whole json

Comment: I'm not here to do your homework. You asked for a regex and now you have it

Comment: Well the regex changes if you use single url vs the whole json, thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Can't you parse the JSON and then match for all elements?

Comment: Well i want to replace all the server names with another server at one go if thats possible, will parse it as a last resort.

Comment: @Farhan You should not be using regex to parse JSON, there are JSON parsers that should be doing this for you, such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).  Once you extract the data you want from the JSON, then you would use the regex provided here to extract the domain/server from the URL

Comment: @JNYRanger Well the JSON i posted is just a small part of a large JSON which is used to create a Java object having deep hierarchy, so instead of navigating the java object and updating the individual url was trying to do it in one go.

Comment: @Farhan Sounds like a terrible idea.  Don't take lazy shortcuts like this.  This leads to bad code and maintenance issues down the road.  Also, regular expression engines are NOT parsers, so don't use them as such.  Instead you can combine the technologies to reach your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like that:

```
^.*http.*//(\S+)/upload/ima.*
```

**Edit:** including a JAVA example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*http.*//(\\S+)/upload/ima.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(nextLine);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Check: [Using Regular Expressions to Extract a Value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java)