# Matching "-" has completely unexpected results

Tags: java, regex

I have an expression that could be `13.33`, `15.66-17.22`, `17.33-17.66`.  I want to be able to figure out if it has a `"-"` (en-dash) in it because that will change how my code runs.  I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java) thread to check for matches in an expression.

My regex to find the en-dash is `"-"`.  My regex expression works online as can be seen [here](http://regexr.com/3cg7u), but fails when used in Java.  My code is as follows.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-");
Matcher m = p.matcher(refVal);
System.out.println(m.find());
if (m.find()){
    //Do stuff  
}
```

With the entry, `17.33–17.66 ref`, the code prints `false`.

The expected use cases:

```
Input: 17.33-17.66 reasdfkljasdfjlkadsf
Output: m.find() should be true

Input: 17.33
Output: m.find() should be false

Input: 2-3 five blah foo
Output: m.find() should be true
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work.

Comment: Down vote explain?  I have an MVCE and I have explained pretty much everything?

Comment: If you use an en-dash in the pattern, [it will get matched](http://ideone.com/jbG4dd).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that in your input string the dash is `–` (150 ascii), while the dash in the pattern is `-` (45 ascii). [Reference](http://www.ascii-code.com/)

Comment: @intboolstring, you mean in the reference or using regex?

Comment: Using regex or .contains()

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check the presence of em-dash (or any single character), you can just use `String.contains`, you don't need to use regular expressions for that.

```
refVal.contains("—")
```

To make sure you're testing for [em-dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm), you can use it's Unicode code to check:

```
refVal.contains("\u2014")
```

Comment: @intboolstring can you show us your new code with this working? Because I think you're doing something wrong at this point. Unless you're testing with the wrong dash, perhaps, as the other answer suggests.

Comment: Are you sure you're using http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm em-dash in both your tested string and contains?

Comment: The original string contains an *en*-dash, not em-dash. See [here](http://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%E2%80%93%E2%80%94).

Comment: Ok - didn't know the difference.