# How to check numeric using Regular Expressions in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have given file name as

```
B-018 MyName
```

I want to check whether first four characters are in format of

'B-< Numeric >< Numeric >< Numeric >

B- will be constant for all names and i want to check if three succeeding characters are numeric.

How to do it using Regular Expressions in Java?

Comment: You should really look at some basic regular expression syntax :). Or show us what you've tried

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java

Answer (score 0):

The following expression implements your requirement.

```
java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("B-\\d{3} .*").matcher("B-018 MyName").matches()
```

It checks that the expressions is "B-(3-digits) (any character zero or more time)".

I advise you to use a site as https://regex101.com/ to learn some basis about regex and test your expressions. This expression can be retrieved using this link https://regex101.com/r/B0GN8F/1.