# Extract multiple dates (dd-MMM-yyyy format) from a string in java

Tags: java, regex, string, date

I have searched everywhere for this but couldn't get a specific solution, and the documentation also didn't cover this. So I want to extract the start date and end date from this string `"1-Mar-2019 to 31-Mar-2019"`. The problem is I'm not able to extract both the date strings.

I found the closest solution here but couldn't post a comment asking how to extract values individually due to low reputation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8116229/10735227

I'm using a regex pattern to look for the occurrences and to extract both occurrences to 2 strings first.
**Here's what I tried:**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\\d{4})");  
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while(m.find())
{
    startdt = m.group(1); 
    enddt = m.group(1);   //I think this is wrong, don't know how to fix it
}
System.out.println("startdt: "+startdt+" enddt: "+enddt);
```

**Output is:**

```
startdt: 31-Mar-2019 enddt: 31-Mar-2019
```

Additionally I need to use DateFormatter to convert the string to date (adding the trailing 0 before single digit date if required).

Comment: Actually, you extract the two dates with your code. It takes two iterations in the while block. Do you mean to get both with 1 regex "at once"?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew or better no while loop at all.

Comment: maybe you can do something like this
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\\d{4}) to (\\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\\d{4})");  
  Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
  while(m.find())
  {
      startdt = m.group(1); 
      enddt = m.group(2);   
  }

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I mean to get the 2 dates into the 2 strings whether at once or through a loop if required

Comment: Then `s.split("\\s*to\\s*")` would do, I think.

Comment: Do you know that you have two date in your line ?

Comment: so see my answer below

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the string will have 2 dates but could have from at the beginning some times. Should I edit the question?

Comment: Thanks, I will try these solutions

Comment: @AxelH yes it'll have 2 dates

Comment: @ArunKoundinya FYI: with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56848621/3832970), you are not checking a range. You will get `2-Feb-2019` and `1-Mar-2019` in `2-Feb-2019: 1-Mar-2019 to 31-Mar-2019`, not the expected `1-Mar-2019` and `31-Mar-2019`. It is OK as per your question title though. Just your data implies that you need to match ranges.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for the info but the string will have just the 2 dates, so I see no problem with it, I can use your solution in case that situation does come up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch both dates simply calling the `find` method twice, if you only have one, this would only capture the first one :

```
String str = "1-Mar-2019 to 31-Mar-2019";

String startdt = null, enddt = null;

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\\d{4})");  
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if(m.find()) {
    startdt = m.group(1); 
    if(m.find()) {
       enddt = m.group(1);
    }
}   
System.out.println("startdt: "+startdt+" enddt: "+enddt);
```

Note that this could be used with a `while(m.find())` and a `List<String` to be able to extract every date your could find.

Comment: Best suggestion this far, imho. You might also use a longer regex including two dates and capture tham as group 1 and group 2.

Comment: @OleV.V. it was the second part of my answer but [Wiktor Stribiżew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56848631/4391450) post it first ;)

Answer (score 1):

If your text may be messy, and you really need to use a regex to extract the date range, you may use

```
String str = "Text here 1-Mar-2019 to 31-Mar-2019 and tex there";
String startdt = "";
String enddt = "";

String date_rx = "\\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\\d{4}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(" + date_rx + ")\\s*to\\s*(" + date_rx + ")");  
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if(m.find())
{
    startdt = m.group(1); 
    enddt = m.group(2); 
}
System.out.println("startdt: "+startdt+" enddt: "+enddt);
// => startdt: 1-Mar-2019 enddt: 31-Mar-2019
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/5V78K1)

Also, consider this enhancement: match the date as whole word to avoid partial matches in longer strings:

```
Pattern.compile("\\b(" + date_rx + ")\\s*to\\s*(" + date_rx + ")\\b")
```

If the range can be expressed with `-` or `to` you may replace `to` with `(?:to|-)`, or even `(?:to|\\p{Pd})` where `\p{Pd}` matches *any* hyphen/dash.

Comment: I went for `Pattern.compile(regexDate + ".*?" + regexDate);` but didn't had the time to post it! This would be the cleanest way to get both date in one regex

Comment: @AxelH I am not sure `.*?` is best to detect a datetime range, it is usually expressed with `to` or dashes, so I suggest `date_rx + \s*(?:to|\p{Pd})\s* + date_rx`.

Comment: Yeah, I used a lazy quantifier simply to keep the example readable. But I like that you didn't include the group in `date_rx`, it is reusable !

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `String::split`

```
String range = "1-Mar-2019 to 31-Mar-2019";
String dts [] = range.split(" ");
System.out.println(dts[0]);
System.out.println(dts[2]);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still want to know how to extract the occurrences through regex, because the string could possibly change (but still have the dates)