# matching but extracting string via regex in java

Tags: java, regex

Trying to extract the id portion of the url string.

```
if(request.getPathInfo().matches("/products/(.*?)")) {
    // use the id portion
    // request.getPathInfo().split("/")[2] // simple attempt
} else if(request.getPathInfo().matches("/orders/(.*?)")) {
    // use the id 
}
```

Example string

```
/products/5d3abb1c30431b78fcf02290
/orders/5d3abb1c30431b78fcf01192
```

**Edit**

Attempt

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("/users/(.*?)").matcher(request.getPathInfo());

if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0)); // /users/
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // empty string or null
} else {
    System.out.println("not found");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Regular Expressions to Extract a Value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java)

Comment: sorry not a duplicated, i need help, something wrong with this regex, it's not picking up, `group(0)` returns `/users/` but `group(1)` returns empty

Comment: What's the `?` for, in your regex?

Comment: want to match any string, for instance an identifier like `5d3abb1c30431b78fcf02290`

Comment: thanks for the pointer, it's working without `?`

Comment: on a side note, can someone suggest an efficient way for multiple urls, let's say if I match `/users` I don't need to match `/orders` and vice versa, an efficient branching structure please?