# Matcher doesn't return the matched regex, instead returns whole string in group(0) (Java)

Tags: java, design-patterns, matcher

The problem I'm facing is that upon following the question at this link, [Using Regular Expressions to Extract a Value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java), I am unable to extract the correct group of the String

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("I have .*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("I have apples");

if(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

What I get:

```
I have apples
```

What I want to get:

```
apples
```

I've tried asking for `m.group(1)` as well but it throws me an exception.

How should I go about this?

Comment: You need to place what you need as the result into a capturing group. Something like `"I have (\w+)"`

Comment: Gives the exact same result, `I have apples`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define a capturing group to get `m.group(...)` work correctly.

Change your pattern to

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("I have (.*)");
```

`m.group(0)` *'denotes the entire pattern'*
`m.group(1)` now returns the expected **'apple'**

Comment: Holy- Thanks that definetely helped a lot