# How to compare String value to another string after using getText()?

Tags: java, string, selenium, selenium-webdriver, compare

When I extract tooltiptext using `getText()` method, output
comes in three lines:

```
outside 
temperature
20c
```

But how to compare extracted `20c` to another string `30c`?

My approach:

```
if (tooltiptext.getText() > 30c) {
    System.out.println("temperature is too low outside");
} else {
    System.out.println("temperature is hot outside");
}
```

Comment: Don't compare strings. Extract the numerical part, convert to a number, and compare those.

Comment: you should split the string on the new line character `\n` then keep only the one you need

Comment: @soundwave How to do that?

Comment: "*`if(tooltiptext.getText()>30c){`*" - This is not legal java syntax; `30c` is not a literal.

Comment: @Turing85 How to do that?

Comment: Please read: [Using Regular Expressions to Extract a Value in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java)

Comment: `Scanner s = new Scanner(getText());` is also an option with `s.nextLine`

Comment: You need to isolate the numerical value, then convert it to an `Integer` or `Double`. Then you can compare it reliably. `split` your input to get the individual lines, then use a regex to find the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
String tooltipText = "outside\ntemperature\n20c";
// ensure that we parse only the last line, so if digits appear in the other lines, there is no impact
String toolipTempText = tooltipText.split("\n")[2];
int tempInCelsius = Integer.parseInt(toolipTempText.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
if (tempInCelsius > 30) {
  System.out.println("temperature is too low outside");
} else {
  System.out.println("temperature is too hot outside");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following:

```
int tempInCelsius = Integer.parseInt(getText().replaceAll("(?s).*?\\b(\\d+)c\\b.*", "$1"));
```

Comment: I am getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException` when I try to print `tempInCelsius`.

Comment: @JackieM [Cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/3Kp6mT).

Comment: *I'm getting...* You *did* copy and paste the code right..?